# Increase gap between bottom of text and top of footer in Word

Tags: microsoft-word

I want to increase the space between the bottom of the text body and the top of the footer, the two currently look too close. I have seen articles on changing the margin but this does not seem to help.

Comment: One way to accomplish this is to go to Font Settings for the text in the Footer. In the first tab for Font Settings, under Spacing, you can set the distance before and after the font. This is independent of Margins. See it this works for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Double click on the footer, then head to the "Layout" tab. In the "Paragraph" section you can change spacing. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Even better would be to modify the Space-before paragraph setting in the Footer Style. That way it will apply even if you change your footer.

If you need help doing that, write back (comment) and I will be glad to give step-by-step instructions.

Answer (score 0):

I use Word 365. Double-click on the footer. Put the cursor on the line of the footer. Select Enter repeatedly, and as you do, space will increase between the body of the text and the footer for the entire document.

Comment: How is this better than accepted answer?